# Add custom non-cms page to spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

There is a requirement to add a custom page without CMS Integration. So, far it is configured like described below.

```
    RouterModule.forChild([{
      path: 'test/bla',
      component: TransactionListPageComponent,
      canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    }]),
```

The page is rendered without issues. Still there are calls against OCC CMS REST API which return 404. Can we avoid those calls?

Comment: I don't think, CMS page api will be called - if you don't add CmsPage Guard.

Comment: @AshishKumar - unfortunately, it is still called, even without CmsPageGuard.